# Como fazer um SELECT DISTINCT junto com o COUNT no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Então, eu preciso fazer um SELECT que busque no banco informações sobre todas as atividades das empresas e retorne a soma de todas as "QNTD_PROCESSOS" daquela atividade. Estou tentando fazer um select count junto com o distinct, porém não estou conseguindo.

Vou mostrar até o ponto que cheguei e depois falar como eu gostaria que ficasse. Vou postar o código jQuery mas não é muito necessário para entendimento da pergunta.

```js
function preencher_empresas() {
  var conta; //Variável para controlar o número de empresas que vem do banco e para manipular o "loader" da página 

  $.ajax({
    //dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "../banco/banco-vision/pagina-relatorios/preencher-relatorio.php",
    cache: false,

  }).done(function(data) {

    var relatorio = "";

    $("#registros-relatorios").empty(); //LIMPAR LISTA

    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, relat) {
      //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 

      relatorio += '<tr>';

      relatorio += '<td>' + relat.DEPARTAMENTO + '</td>';
      relatorio += '<td>' + relat.COD + '</td>';
      relatorio += '<td>' + relat.EMPRESAS + '</td>';
      relatorio += '<td>' + relat.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
      relatorio += '<td>' + relat.TIPO_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
      relatorio += '<td>' + relat.QNTD_PROCESSOS + '</td>';

      relatorio += '</tr>';


    });

    $('#registros-relatorios').html(relatorio);

    $("div#loading-relatorio").hide();

  }).fail(function() {
    alert('Falha na listagem dos usuários');
  }).always(function() {});
}
```

```html
<?php

 //ARQUIVO CRIADO PARA PREENCHER A TABELA COM DADOS DO BANCO AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA

 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 
 require_once("../../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php"); // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO
 
 // CONSULTA GERAL DO BANCO  QUE RETORNA O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA DA PÁGINA INTERFACE.PHP 
  
 session_start(); 
 
 
 $departamento_usuario = $_SESSION["departamento-usuario"];
   
 $select_relatorio = "SELECT DEPARTAMENTO, RESPONSAVEL, COD, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO, TIPO_ATIVIDADE, QNTD_PROCESSOS FROM tbl_atividades WHERE DEPARTAMENTO = '$departamento_usuario' ORDER BY EMPRESAS";
 $lista_relatorio = mysqli_query($conecta, $select_relatorio);
   
 if(!$lista_relatorio)
 {
  die("Erro no Banco - Erro no select na tabela tbl_atividades");
  exit;
 }
 
 $retorno_relatorio = array();
 while($linha_relatorio = mysqli_fetch_object($lista_relatorio))
 {    
   
  $retorno_relatorio[] = $linha_relatorio;
    
 }  
 
 
 //JSON QUE VAI PARA O RETORNO DO AJAX COM DADOS DA CONSULTA DO SELECT
 echo json_encode($retorno_relatorio);  

?>
```

**IMAGEM DA DESCRIÇÃO DA TABELA EM QUE É REALIZADA A CONSULTA.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**IMAGEM DE COMO ESTÁ SAINDO:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vocês repararem, algumas atividades se repetem. EU gostaria que elas não se repetissem e ali na TD "Processos Executados" mostrasse a soma de todas as atividades que fossem iguais (do mesmo tipo, da mesma empresa). (Não sei se consegui ser claro).

- Tentei fazer com um SELECT DISTINCT, mas não obtive êxito. Consegui fazer com que as atividades não se repitam, porém não consegui ver um jeito de mostrar a soma dessas atividades.
- Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou usar o `GROUP BY`, mas o `DISTINCT` teria que funcionar, talvez retirar o PHP e JS da pergunta e colocar a estrutura do banco e a consulta, a pergunta fique melhor

Comment: @LeonardoBarros , como ficaria essa query ? Vou colocar a estrutura da tabela em que eu faço a consulta. O banco não foi eu que fiz. A tabela está meio que desorganziada, porém está funcional.

Comment: Eu tinha me expressado mal. Na verdade eu gostaria de obter a Soma da quantidade de Processos das atividades que se repetem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você Usar COUNT e DISTINCT vai gerar o valor de 1 para cada linha.

Faz algo parecido com isso:*texto grifado*

```
SELECT 
    DEPARTAMENTO, 
    RESPONSAVEL, 
    COD, 
    EMPRESAS, 
    TRIBUTACAO, 
    TIPO_ATIVIDADE,
    SUM(QNTD_PROCESSOS) AS QNTD_PROCESSOS
FROM tbl_atividades 
WHERE DEPARTAMENTO = '$departamento_usuario' 
GROUP BY
    DEPARTAMENTO, 
    RESPONSAVEL, 
    COD, 
    EMPRESAS, 
    TRIBUTACAO, 
    TIPO_ATIVIDAD
ORDER BY 
    EMPRESAS
```

No Group você monta o organização que precisar, ele vai juntar tudo que é igual, depois só ajustar no Select, se vai fazer COUNT, SUM, AVG, ou o que for mais conveniente pra resolução do seu problema.

Comment: Eu tinha me expressado mal. Na verdade eu gostaria de obter a Soma da quantidade de Processos das atividades que se repetem.

Answer (score 0):

Boa dia,
Experimenta:

```
$select_relatorio = "SELECT TIPO_ATIVIDADE, count(TIPO_ATIVIDADE) as 'contagem' FROM tbl_atividades WHERE DEPARTAMENTO = '$departamento_usuario' group by TIPO_ACTIVIDADE";
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso dos outros campos para preencher a tabela que se encontra no HTML. Eles não teriam que estar nesse SELECT ?

Comment: Eu tinha me expressado mal. Na verdade eu gostaria de obter a Soma da quantidade de Processos das atividades que se repetem.

Comment: Nesse caso em vez de count(TIPO_ACTIVIDADE) coloca count(QNTD_PROCESSOS). E adiciona também os restantes campos ao select, colocando eles também no group by

Comment: Teria que utilizar o SUM, ao invés do COUNT.